# Java compiler API convert TypeMirror to Type

Tags: java, types, compiler-construction

I hardly ever used the Java compiler API before, so I have very little experience with it. I want to get the type of the class my MethodTree is in as a `Type`. This is what ChatGPT gave me, but it returns a `TypeMirror`:

```java
private TypeMirror getTypeOfMethodClass(MethodTree methodTree, Trees trees, CompilationUnitTree compilationUnit) {
    TreePath path = trees.getPath(compilationUnit, methodTree);
    while (path != null && !(path.getLeaf() instanceof ClassTree)) {
        path = path.getParentPath();
    }
    if (path != null) {
        TypeElement typeElement = (TypeElement) trees.getElement(path);
        return typeElement.asType();
    }
    return null;
}
```

How can I "cast" `TypeMirror` to `Type`?